# Bootstrap 3 - nav-justified not showing properly when you maximize window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [this example page from Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/) and I have small problem with that nav-justified navigation. When you minimize window, it will correctly transform to a mobile version. But when you maximize window, buttons are still in mobile version format. You can see this problem directly on that example page - it's not only on my side. Can you help me fix this problem? Thanks!

Browser: Google Chrome
Resolution: 1920x1080

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-justified :

> ### WebKit and responsive justified navs
>
> Chrome and Safari both exhibit a bug in which resizing your browser horizontally causes rendering errors in the justified nav that are cleared upon refreshing. This bug is also shown in the justified nav example.